# How to fetch .JPG to HTML, from MySQL DB using Flask?

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask, mysql-python

I have a Flask app which runs Selenium to extract an image through XPATH.
The .JPG image is saved to MySQL DB (Binary), then it *should* be rendered to HTML. The problem is that it isn't rendered.

Any thoughts?

## Column Type:

```
profile_picture = Column(BLOB)
```

## Get the image using Selenium:

```
profile_picture = WebDriverWait(browser, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
        "//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/div/button/img")))

src = profile_picture.get_attribute('src')
```

## Save the picture to the DB (MySQL):

```
settings_db.profile_picture = profile_picture
```

## Fetching the image from the DB:

```
profile_picture = TABLE.query.filter_by(username=current_user.username).first()
profile_picture = profile_picture.profile_picture
```

## Rendering (FLASK):

```
return render_template('index.html', profile_picture=profile_picture)
```

## HTML:

```
<img src="{{ profile_picture }}" alt="User Image">
```

The image is never displayed and the output in HTML between braces is 'unknown'.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that binary objects shouldn't be transported between layers. Did you tried to convert image to Base64 src format?

```
<div>
<p>Taken from wikpedia</p>
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
</div>
```

You could use this method:

```
encoded_image = base64.b64encode(profile_picture).decode()
encoded_image_str = "data:image/png;base64,{encoded_image}".format(encoded_image=encoded_image)
```